# Removing lines that don't follow another

Tags: qgis, line, virtual-layer

[image: Trying to remove extra pink lines]

I have two line layers, the blue and the pink. I've already modified the pink one by snapping to the blue (i.e. there are pink lines that match the blue underneath), however now I want to get rid of the excess pink ones. 
I've tried to remove them using v.clean, but using option 'rmdangle' just produces exactly the same layer.

I've also tried using a virtual layer with this query:

```
SELECT l1.*

FROM line AS l1, line AS l2

WHERE st_intersects(start_point(l1.geometry),end_point(l2.geometry))

OR st_intersects(start_point(l2.geometry),end_point(l1.geometry))

GROUP BY l1.id
```

but that gives me a weird result and definitely does not get rid of the excess pink lines.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is wrong with `clip`?

Comment: @Erik doesn't that only work with selecting features inside polygons? I have just thought I could buffer around the blue line, then use select by location to only select lines within the buffer. Problem with this is that not all snapped lines are exactly on the blue line, some are slightly out so its finding a size that captures pink lines running parallel with blue, but not big enough to capture short pink lines.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @Erik - tried clip? yes, with just the lines it doesn't work - it will only let me select a polygon as an overlay layer. Tried clip by buffering the blue line but obviously then I end up with tiny parts of the excess pink lines.

Comment: @Erik - trying select by location now.